# Select one record after order by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i have a bunch of CD's that contain a bunch of artwork. I want to display a thumb image of each CD on a webpage and for that i need to pick just one image out of the many artwork that exist for that CD...

The query selects all of the artwork and i group by position and want to pick the first one. I don't no how to pick just the first image FOR EACH RECORD after i've order them...

The query is as following:

```
SELECT release_artwork.release_id, release_artwork.position, artwork.small_filename, artwork.small_width, artwork.small_height
FROM release_artwork
JOIN artwork ON artwork.artwork_id = release_artwork.artwork_id
ORDER BY release_artwork.position
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for only one for each position or just one row for the result set?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear to me. Does `release_id` correspond to an album, or does `position`? You can probably add a `GROUP BY` on whichever column you want to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a MySQL instance handy, but this should work - just define an inline table to hold the minimums, then join to that.

```
SELECT release_artwork.release_id, release_artwork.position, artwork.small_filename, artwork.small_width, artwork.small_height
FROM
  release_artwork
  inner JOIN artwork ON artwork.artwork_id = release_artwork.artwork_id
  inner join
  (
  SELECT
    ra.release_id as release_id
   ,min(ra.position) as rap
  FROM
    release_artwork ra
  group by
    ra.release_id
  ) mins
  on mins.release_id = release_artwork.release_id
    and mins.rap = release_artwork.position
ORDER BY
  release_artwork.release_id
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use `LIMIT 1`, to limit the results you retrieve to just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT release_artwork.release_id, release_artwork.position, artwork.small_filename, artwork.small_width, artwork.small_height
FROM release_artwork
JOIN artwork ON artwork.artwork_id = release_artwork.artwork_id
ORDER BY release_artwork.position LIMIT 1
```

Adding the `LIMIT 1` at the end will limit it to a single result.

Comment: true. i've edited my question so it's clearer that i want to limit 1 row for each release_id